# Finding starts, ends, and loops with pydot

Tags: python, graphviz, pydot

Is there a way to achieve this in pydot?

Take the following example:

[Outputted Dot File]

```
strict graph g{
"A" -> "B";
"B" -> "C";
"C" -> "D";
"D" -> "E";
}
```

[Python]

```
print(num.start)
>>> A
print(num.steps)
>>> ["a,b","b,c","c,d","d,e"]
print(num.end)
>>> E
```

or with the following case:

[Outputted Dot File]

```
strict graph g{
"A" -> "B";
"B" -> "C";
"C" -> "A";
}
```

[Python]

```
if num["A"] == num.loop:
print("[%s] loop detected")%(num["A"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pydot can write dot files, but it is not for analyzing graphs.

You want [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov) instead. It can [read and write dot files](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.nx_pydot), [find circles](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.cycles.html#module-networkx.algorithms.cycles), find reachable nodes and do topological sort.

Look up the terminology of graphs on wikipedia and NetworkX can do the rest.

Comment: For future reference, I have an example of a python script using networkx to identify cycles in dot graphs at: http://blog.jasonantman.com/2012/03/python-script-to-find-dependency-cycles-in-graphviz-dot-files/ Thanks Jochen for giving me the links to come up with the script.

Comment: Your links are long dead.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have the whole graph structure, via `graph.get_edge_list()` you can implement standard depth first search to find shortest path between nodes.  Finding loops is likewise done with [standard graph algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection).  See this article on [Graph implementations in Python](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) for sourcecode on how to do shortest path between two nodes.

If you're looking for the pydot library do do this for you, you might be out of luck.